# Login timeout expired when connecting to SQL database via pyodbc on jupyter notebook despite successful connection in ODBC Data Source Administrator

Tags: python, sql-server, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

I am receiving this error prompt:

> OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

when connecting to an SQL database using pyodbc in a jupyter notebook. My code is as follows:

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = ("Server=xxx.database.windows.net;"
    +"PORT=1433;"
    +"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    +"Database=xxx;"
    +"Connection Timeout=60;"
    +"Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;"
    +"UID=xxxx;"
    )

 cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

When running the code, the cell just loads for a long time and then shows the aformentioned error. There is supposed to be a multi-factor authentication prompt to come out, but, unfortunately, none appears. I am suspecting that this might be causing the issue.

I have tried testing the database connection in ODBC Data Source Administrator using the same login inputs as in the code above. In contrast, the MFA prompt properly popped up and the connection was successful:

> Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 17.10.0003
>
> Running connectivity tests...
>
> Attempting connection
> Connection established
> Verifying option settings
> INFO: A network alias was found for the DSN server. 'Protocol: xxx; Address: xxxx.database.windows.net' was used to establish the connection.
> INFO: Connection was encrypted with server certificate validation.
> Disconnecting from server
>
> TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!

I also tried:

- running the notebook both in VSCode and in an edge browser, with the latter allowing redirects and popups
- applying firewall exemption for port 1433
- adding `TrustServerCertificate=yes;` and `ENCRYPT=yes`
- accessing the database through MSSQL and was successful
- removing the port parameter and adding `,<port number>` to the server name

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you on Windows? i.e.: `ActiveDirectoryInteractive` is only a supported option on Windows platform.

Comment: How do you think Python behind Jupyter should prompt you for your MFA code? Have you tried using mechanisms to collect authentication tokens, such as `from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential` that you could then pass in via `pyodbc.connect()`'s `AcessToken` parameter?

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning. For your second comment, yes I tried to no avail.

For the first comment, yes I am using Windows. However, your first comment made me realize that I was running the notebook in a Linux virtual environment. Switched to a Windows environment and it worked just fine. Thanks!